# How to combine 2 SELECTs which have INNER JOIN together?

Tags: php, sql, select

Use PHP and MySQL and have 2 SELECT statements to combine together

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT t1.* 
      FROM entry  AS t1
      INNER JOIN entry_tag AS t2 ON t1.entry_id=t2.entry_id
      INNER JOIN tag AS t3 ON t3.tag_id=t2.tag_id 
      WHERE t1.title LIKE '%$key%' OR
      t1.content LIKE '%$key%' OR
      t3.tag LIKE '%$key%'  AND t1.status='OK'
      ORDER BY view  DESC";
```

---

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT t1.* 
      FROM entry  AS t1
      INNER JOIN candidate AS t2 ON t1.entry_id=t2.entry_id 
      WHERE t2.name LIKE '%$key%' AND t1.status='OK'
      ORDER BY view  DESC";
```

How to combine these 2 SELECTs into 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use UNION ALL:

```
  $sql="SELECT DISTINCT t1.* 
    FROM entry  AS t1
    INNER JOIN entry_tag AS t2 ON t1.entry_id=t2.entry_id
    INNER JOIN tag AS t3 ON t3.tag_id=t2.tag_id 
    WHERE t1.title LIKE '%$key%' OR
    t1.content LIKE '%$key%' OR
    t3.tag LIKE '%$key%'  AND t1.status='OK'
  UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.* 
    FROM entry  AS t1
    INNER JOIN candidate AS t2 ON t1.entry_id=t2.entry_id 
    WHERE t2.name LIKE '%$key%' AND t1.status='OK'
    ORDER BY view  DESC";
```

Comment: Yes, you can. But you must provide the same columns per each select. Also, if you want to exclude duplicates at the end of the query, use UNION instead of UNION ALL.

Comment: That's what I want -'exclude duplications'. Thanks again Parkyprg. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from
(SELECT DISTINCT t1.* 
  FROM entry  AS t1
  INNER JOIN entry_tag AS t2 ON t1.entry_id=t2.entry_id
  INNER JOIN tag AS t3 ON t3.tag_id=t2.tag_id 
  WHERE t1.title LIKE '%$key%' OR
  t1.content LIKE '%$key%' OR
  t3.tag LIKE '%$key%'  AND t1.status='OK'
  ORDER BY view  DESC")
union all
("SELECT DISTINCT t1.* 
  FROM entry  AS t1
  INNER JOIN candidate AS t2 ON t1.entry_id=t2.entry_id 
  WHERE t2.name LIKE '%$key%' AND t1.status='OK'
  ORDER BY view  DESC")
```

Comment: Which one is the best between having "(" , ")" and not have one like Parkyprg's answer?

Comment: @AJ - Either way will work. I just prefer with parenthesis so if I will add a sorting expression after the query was combined `select...(select..) union all (select...) order by...`, I can do so.